# How to setup Firebase Admin with Java

Tags: java-server, firebase-admin

I'm trying to setup Firebase admin with Java and the official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) are not helping enough.

It says that prerequisite is a Java server and I'm not sure what that means. Is it like, that you have to build the server yourself using sockets? Or there allready is a Java server that you can use? I mean, one thing is a server and another thing is server application. And they say that you need server, well can I download the server program from somewhere or do I need to build it myself? I'm pretty puzzled if I need to build it myself...

I really don't understand, how do I simply add code they provided to my Java server?? Or what do they even mean by Java server? I really don't know how to do this, I haven't found not a one tutorial besides that one on their page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a java project not a server. Documentation over there was a tutorial for implementation of firebase to SDK (JAVA) .

Comment: okay, I am now trying with a basic Java project (in Itellij), I paste the code they've provided, run it, and I get error that I don't have some libraries that Firebase uses. When I download the library that I was missing, I get error that I'm missing the next. Do you maybe know what are all the libraries that I need? I mean, there really should be some list in my opinion. Thanks.

Comment: @Scarass did you get any more help with this? I'm stuck at the same point.

Comment: @Lewis Black you need to use somekind of dependency manager like Maven or Gradle and it'll download all the dependencies you need automatically.